# implement midleware next with errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am writing a node js application using typescript.
I want to use the middleware pattern similar to the midllware pattern used in express js.
what is mean is i want to have a stack of handlers that every handler that finishes calls the next handler in the chain. my problem is how do i handle errors.
If a handler has an error he should call the next error midllewar. 
How do i do that?
what i tried to do for now is having a chain of classes each call a run method on and object which is a dictionary of parameters but im stuck with how to handle the errors. how to switch to the error middleware
any sample code will help...
thatnk

```
export class midlleware {

   public execute(object);

}

....
const p ={};
p.data = // some data 
foreach (const m in this.middlewares) {
   m.execute(o)
}
```

Comment: There are a zillion ways to do this and you don't really show us enough of what you're trying to accomplish in order to know which method is appropriate.  In the code you show, your `m.execute(o)` could either return an error value which you would check for or it could throw an exception which you can catch.  In either case, you can then detect when the middleware function has an error.  The `next()` scheme that Express uses does not work like this at all.

Comment: how does express implemts it?

Comment: You have full access to the Express code.  This is some of the [relevant code from Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L98).